# DDD Sample Application - Where's the hsqldb?

Tags: java, domain-driven-design, hsqldb

I downloaded the DDD Sample Application (based on book by Eric Evans) and it uses a hsqldb. However, I can't seem to find how this db is set up. I opened the project in Intellij and everything builds like a charm. But nowhere do I find such a hsqldb... I'm not an experienced Java developer, so I'm probably missing something. Anyone that can answer this for me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HSQLDB (also called HypersonicDB) is usually used as an embedded SQL database in trivial java apps. You can download it [here](http://hsqldb.org/). It's very simple to set up, and usually works just by having the JAR file in your classpath, the sample app should have the appropriate config.

Comment: And the db itself? I mean, the tables and data, can it be it's included in the jar?

Comment: @Lieven: That depends on how the app uses it. It's often a purely in-memory database. The app might choose to specify file storage, but you shouldn't have to do anything to make it work.

Comment: So, jdbc:hsqldb:mem:dddsample, would be created automatically? And then hibernate would create the tables if their weren't any? I have the impression that the Persistence tests assume there's already data in the db, so I'm trying to find how the db is set up...

Comment: Yes, `jdbc:hsqldb:mem` will create an in-memory database on demand, and hibernate most likely is configured to create the tables on demand. The persistence tests may pre-load test data into the database.